# Reloading AQGridview

Tags: iphone, ios, aqgridview

I am making an iOS app that uses AQGridview to present a list of image files in the documents directory. Files are constantly being added and deleted from the direcotry. Is there anyway that I could "reload" my AQGridview to show/remove data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your datasource (array, or whatever) and then call reloadData on your GridView.

```
// Rerfresh the grid
[self.grid reloadData];
```

Unless your question if more about how to detect the changes in the directory?